# lots of rest calls vs core data in mobile commerce app

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, mobile

I'm rather inexperience with iOS and currently trying to build a simple mobile shopping app.
I have a solid and scalable nodeJS backend that communicates with an SQL database from another project and want to  use the data stored in that db.

Now I'm wondering what would make more sense: getting the data I need in each view via REST calls or  trying to make fewer calls and having more data in some core data model. I'm fairly new to the latter. Any literature on which arguments exist with regards to perfomance is also more than welcome!

Thanks heaps.
Max

Comment: Remember that mobile latency is considerably worse than fixed/WiFi. But also remember a lot of people are on capped or latent+slow connections.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about a mobile shopping app, I'd recommend you to use Core data for your Catalog because there are very less chances of products and categories being modified and that's the section of the app that's accessed most frequently. It'll make the app load faster and you'll have to make fewer network calls. You can fetch Catalog data once a day from your server or whatever time sounds more reasonable to you but fetching and updating cart, making payment, checkout etc. must be handled on server side for which you'll be required to make API calls, every time they're accessed.